# Will a time series database be a better fit for our data?

Tags: mysql, performance, time-series-database

I work on a website where users can play and download audio. Each time a visitor plays or downloads a piece of audio, that usage is recorded for statistics.

We have two MySQL tables where we keep this statistics :

- `entityusage` : details about the entity played or downloaded. An entity can be a track, album or playlist (only tracks can be played, but albums or playlists can be downloaded).
- `entityusage_file` : details about the files related to the played or downloaded entity. A track, album or playlist will always translate into at least one audio file.

The data model looks like this :

[image]

Both of these tables contains about 40.000.000 rows. We use these two tables to present download statistics for internal usage, but due to the size of these tables performance is lagging. A query easily takes a minute or two two complete.

*Typically, what we do is that we need to figure out the number of downloads and playbacks for a given time interval - and group downloads and playbacks by e.g.  day, month or year.*

- At first, we queried these tables directly to generate statistics for our own usage. The amount of data eventually grew to big for this approach to perform well.
- We then started to "collapse" the data by setting up a process which moves data from `entityusage` and `entityusage_file` into tables such as `entityusage_trackbyday`, `entityusage_trackbymonth` and `entityusage_trackbyyear`. This way, we reduced the amount of data we had to query by pre-grouping data on [track],[interval],[territory].
- Finally, since we're using UUIDs to represent entities - which in itself is can be a bottleneck performance-wise - we converted all UUIDs to BINARY.

[image]

Despite these efforts, we again see performance lagging. We are now considering if other types of databases will be a better match for this purpose.

Overall, what we have is a lot of events which happened at a specific time. We need to run queries over these events to extract the sum of playbacks and/or downloads :

- ...which happened within a specific time interval
- ...filtered by some criteria (territory, action, entitytype)
- ...grouped by e.g. day, month or year.

Will a time series database be a better fit for this type of usage than our current MySQL database? Can we expect better query performance if we move to a time series database?